# Python Error when querying a SQL query (not all arguments converted during string formatting)

Tags: sql, python-3.x, typeerror

I have the below python code that tries to pull some data from a SQL query. I however am getting an error

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Given below is the code I am using

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql
import xlsxwriter

def func(input):
    db_details = conn.cursor() # set DB Cursor

    db_details.execute(sql.SQL("""select name from store where name = (%s)"""), (input))
    names = dwh_cursor.fetchall()

    df = pd.DataFrame(names,columns=[desc[0] for desc in dwh_cursor.description])
```

Could anyone guide me where am I going wrong. Thanks

Comment: How do you call your function `func(...)` and what is in `input` ?

Comment: can you try as `db_details.execute("select name from store where name = (%s)", input)`

Comment: @Corion, this is part of a Python Flask project. I call it like func(store_name) and this throws this error...

Comment: @ikram, tried your suggestion and that throws the same error as well.

Comment: can you try as `db_details.execute("select name from store where name = (%s)", %(input))`

Comment: Thanks was able to extract the required data

Answer (score 0):

If i recall correctly you need to pass to sql query a name included in single quotes, so your query need to be ...where name = '{}' """.format(variablename)